# Preventing iPhone Auto lock via application's plist file

Tags: iphone, ios, cordova

Is there a way to prevent iPhone auto-lock via a plist of an app. More specifically, a PhoneGap application?

I have written an application that uses Phonegap framework. In it, I have few custom plugins, inside which I have included the code

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setIdleTimerDisabled:YES];
```

to disable autolock. But it would be really great if there existed a plist option so that I can configure the app via the plist and not via code.

Cheers!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No — you're only supposed to disable the idle timer when it's absolutely necessary. From the docs:

> You should set this property only if necessary and should be sure to reset it to NO when the need no longer exists.

Having an Info.plist key that disables it for the entirety of the application's lifetime would be against this guideline.

Comment: Ah, thanks very much for that tip.. I actually forgot to reset it to NO. I will add that line now.